# PHP array_merge_recursive with foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

How do you merge a loop of arrays into a single array(maybe object) adding each value to its associated common key?

```
Categories: 

Array ( [category] => introduction [timeZone] => Europe/Stockholm [language] => Danish )

Array ( [category] => introduction [timeZone] => Europe/Stockholm [language] => Danish )

Array ( [category] => e-learning [timeZone] => Europe/Stockholm [language] => German )
```

into

```
Collection

Array ( 
        [category] => Array (e-learning,introduction) 
        [timeZone] => Europe/Stockholm 
        [language] => Array (Danish,German)
)
```

Mycode so far:

```
foreach ($categories as $category){
   $collection = array_merge_recursive($category);
}
```

It seem like array_merge_recursive would achieve my result if I had $array1,$array2 sepcified within the PHP. But I need to do from a foreach loop.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the initial array named `$categories`, Consider:

```
$collection = array_merge_recursive(...$categories);
foreach($collection as &$item) $item = array_unique($item);
```

Output:

```
[
  'category' => ['intro','learning'],
  'timezone' => ['Europe'],
  'language' => ['Danish','German'],
]
```

[**Live demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eecee4da9e42e4b51f48d95286f142be5edc9aac)

Comment: thanks! This is exactly what I was after. Question though, why the  'foreach($collection as &$item) $item = array_unique($item);' as  this also works 'array_unique($collection)'. Just out interest as both return same result

Comment: @Elliott I call `array_unique()` on each member of `$collection` because you want each sub-array to have unique values. Otherwise you might end up with `'category'=>['intro','intro']` if the arrays you merged both had an `intro` value in their `category` sub-arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this tricky solution:

```
$collection = [];
// get keys of a first element of categories
$keys = array_keys($categories[0]);
// iterate over these keys
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    // use `array_unique` to eliminate duplicates
    $collection[] = array_unique(
        // `array_column` will give you all values under `$key`
        array_column($categories, $key)
    );
}
```

Of course this works since php5.5, as in this version we have `array_column`.